# Am I missing something with the .NET MAUI Shell Flyout Menu not showing here?

Tags: maui

Hell all:

Starting up a .NET MAUI shell app and having an issue with the flyout menu???
I cannot see the "hamburger menu" and swiping from side does not seem to work???
Am I missing something???

XAML:

```
<Shell
x:Class="Test.AppShell"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
>

<ShellContent
    Title="Test"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"
    Route="MainPage" />

<FlyoutItem Title="Lookup Items">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MenuPage}"/>
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Logout">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"/>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW ... the hamburger menu item is not visible at the top of the screen???

Comment: For `FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"`, you may not need to set it as this is the default value for the FlyoutBehavior property.

Comment: Yea ... it looks like you do not need to specify flyout OR flyoutvisibility. Both default to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the `ShellContent` with `Tab` inside the `FlyoutItem` to show the hamburger menu. Here's the code snippet for your reference:

```
  <ShellContent

    Title="Test"

    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"

    Route="MainPage" />

  <FlyoutItem Title="Lookup Items">

      <Tab>
           <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
      </Tab>

  </FlyoutItem>

  <FlyoutItem Title="Logout">
      <Tab>
           <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
       </Tab>
  </FlyoutItem>
```

**Update:**

The .NET MAUI platform provides two primary forms of page navigation to an app:

- `Shell`.
- Base navigation pages, such as `NavigationPage` ,`TabbedPage`, and `FlyoutPage`.

You are mixing the `Shell` with `NavigationPage` so the "hamburger menu" disappears. To fix that, you need to set the mainpage like below:

```
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

And then register route for the `ProvisionPage`:

```
public AppShell() 
{
      InitializeComponent();

      Routing.RegisterRoute("ProvisionPage", typeof(ProvisionPage));
}
```

Use the `Shell.Current.GoToAsync` to navigate from `MainPage` to `ProvisionPage`:

```
 await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("ProvisionPage");
```

For more information, you can refer to [.NET MAUI Shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation).

Comment: Yea ... tried this too and no change???

Comment: OK ... I created a new app and added and it is working ??? BUT cannot understand why it is not working on this current app??? Ideas on where to look?

Comment: @BitWiseByteDumb Thanks for the response. So the code should work as expected. Is there any difference between the new created app and current app?

Comment: It appears to be my method of page navigation. My main page is typically the login page unless the device is not provisioned (Must enter creds and company info which are bounced to a server for auth). If the device is NOT provisioned then the main page is set to a provision page like: MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ProvisionPage()); This usage, it seems,  eliminates the hamburger menu availability. Make sense?

Comment: A little more info ... When I login successfully ... I goto a menu page ... like ... await Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage()); Should I not be navigating like this?

Comment: @BitWiseByteDumb That explains it. You can see my update.

Comment: May - You were right! I made some rookie mistakes! Navigation is a little different than what I'm used to! Thanks for the help!